# Adding ssh keys to a new server without having previously set up users on that server

Tags: ssh, vps, ssh-keys, hetzner, ssh-keygen

I've setup a clean new VPS running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Hetzner and would like to access it via ssh.

Here is what I've tried to do:

1. I have added my public ssh key (passphrase-less) in Hetzner's online GUI. That looked something like this:

```
ssh-rsa blahblahblah= my.name@gmail.com
```

2. But when I attempt to `ssh-copy-id` this key to the server, I run into issues. Since I haven't logged into the server to create users, I don't know what to put for the `user` in this command:

```
ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa_pub [user]@serveraddress
```

I've tried adding the key to root user like so:

```
ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa_pub [user]@serveraddress
```

But then I'm prompted for a password I don't know.

---

This leads me to the following questions I've had a hard time finding answers to:

**1.** How can I use `ssh-copy-id` to copy my public key to the server if I haven't setup a user yet?

**2.** What is the default `root` password on the server? How Would I find this out? I've tried `ubuntu`, `root`, the basics.

**3.** What does adding a public key via GUI on the server host's website normally do with regards to server users? Does it add the key to the `known_hosts` file?

**4.** What is the technical significance of the final comment line in my public ssh key, currently `my.name@gmail.com`?

Comment: hetzner's FAG should adress this point. don't you have an option to specify public key during host creation ? (like AWS do for instance)

Comment: You need to find what is the username that was created on the VPS, not just try to guess.

Comment: @Archemar, this wasn't part of the setup. I only have the option of adding my ssh key after the fact, but it doesn't allow me to specify user or anything.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, the thing is I have no idea where to find this out. I can't find anything in the docs or FAQ.

Comment: One would imagine they would mention it here under the "Security - ssh" section: https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/security/ssh/. But I'm not seeing anything helpful.

Comment: It turns out that the root password credentials can be reset within the Hetzner Cloud server interface under the option titled "Rescue".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How can I use ssh-copy-id to copy my public key to the server if I haven't setup a user yet?

You'd need the password for the user, and for SSH to accept passwords (not always the case).  I wouldn't expect this to be the way forward in this sort of situation, where the VPS provider has a copy of your public key.

> 2. What is the default root password on the server? How Would I find this out? I've tried ubuntu, root, the basics.

There's nothing guaranteed; it will be defined by the VPS provider, and should be in their documentation.

> 3. What does adding a public key via GUI on the server host's website normally do with regards to server users? Does it add the key to the
>    known_hosts file?

Close; it would add it to the .ssh/authorized_keys file in some users' home directory.  As you've identified, knowing which user is opaque

> 4. What is the technical significance of the final comment line in my public ssh key, currently my.name@gmail.com?

Nothing technical, it's just a label for human use.

Comment: Regarding 1., so what would you expect is the way forward. How does this typically work? You spin up a new server, which I did, but then they don't tell me how to access it, so I figured there was some standard protocol that I missed. Nowhere in the process did they have me specify users. Also, as far as I've been able to search them, their documentation doesn't specify this either.

Comment: It turns out that the root password credentials can be reset within the Hetzner Cloud server interface under the option titled "Rescue".